# vector elements in ascending order

Tags: c++, function, sorting, vector, boolean

I want to write a boolean function to see if the elements in the vector are in ascending order or not.
My code so far:

```
bool if_sorted(vector<int>& v) {
int i;
for (; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if(v[i] < v[i + 1]){
        break;
    } else {
        return false; 
}
if(v[i] == v.size())
    return true;
}
```

In the main() function I am just typing in the elements of the vector an with the if_sorted() function I want to see if these values are sorted in ascending order or not.

How can I write this boolean function without functions like is_sorted, or modify my existing code?

Comment: 1. You forgot to state a question. 2. You forgot to initialize `i`.

Comment: Take a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted

Comment: I don't want to use is_sorted or other functions. Only from the `iostream` library. `i` is initialized right over the for-loop.

Comment: @user3653164 Not using anything but iostream? because homework? Personally if you are just reading it in, only store the last value and just check `(prev<curval)`. Storing the vector is a waste of memory and time.

Comment: You can write the code many ways. If you want it to work, you might start by looking carefully at the `if (v[i] < v[i+1])`, thinking about it a while, and realizing why your code doesn't work.

Comment: 1. I also think you wanted to do `if (i == v.size())`, and not `v[i]`. 1.5. btw isn't it supposed to be `<=`for the sorting ?
2. you'll exceed v's memory for i == v.size() - 1. you should do in the `for loop`: `i < v.size() - 1`, and it should be `if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) return false;`, and that's it.
3. you can `return true` at the end without checking the last if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool if_sorted(vector<int>& v) {

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
     if(v[i] > v[i + 1]){
        return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about, not using `std::is_sorted`:

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66f156467d60c9ca)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container, 
         typename It = typename Container::const_iterator, 
         typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>
bool if_sorted(Container const &container) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    It l(end(container));
    return l == std::adjacent_find(begin(container),l,std::greater_equal<T>());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    do    std::generate_n(v.begin(), v.size(), rand);
    while (!if_sorted(v));

    std::cout << "Yay, found a vector that was accidentally sorted: \n";
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Printing random, sorted, sequences of 10 integers like

```
Yay, found a vector that was accidentally sorted: 
338521972 564591732 631716774 818567430 923731840 1036769782 1094628595 1228665979 1863863464 2024865477
```